# Why does my code using Langchain with Pinecone take a full minute to generate an answer?

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

Using Langchain with Pinecone, why does it take me a full minute to generate an answer using the following code?

```
def answer_with_pinecone(query, documents, embeddings):
    pinecone.init(api_key=os.environ.get('PINECONE_API_KEY_REVENUED'),
                  environment=os.environ.get('PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT'))
    docsearch = Pinecone.from_texts(
        texts=[t.page_content for t in documents],
        embedding=embeddings, index_name=os.environ.get('index_name'))
    docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
    llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=openai.api_key)
    chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="map_reduce")
    answer = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=query).lstrip()
    return answer
```

I would much rather would take one second especially since this is for a production use case. Thank you very much for any and all constructive criticism. I will be happy to provide more details if necessary. I appreciate your valuable time and and assistance.

I tried running the code that I shared and I was expecting it to be a lot quicker but it was very slow